# Updating DataTable bound to ASP.Net DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, datatable

I am having a problem updating a datatable that is bound to a datagrid. Tried a bunch of approaches but the problem is t**he underlying datatable reverts back to its initial state** everytime u click a command.

Here's the example code:

**On Label Click:**

```
protected void OnUserDataGridCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = DataGridUsers.DataSource as DataTable;

            if (e.CommandName == "Lock Out")
            {
                // Approach 1
                e.Item.Cells[0].Text = "Lock";
                DataGridUsers.DataSource = dt;
                DataGridUsers.DataBind();

                // Approach 2              
                dt.Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex]["FirstName"] = "LOCK";
                dt.Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex].AcceptChanges();

                DataGridUsers.DataSource = dt;
                DataGridUsers.DataBind();                
            }
        }
```

So this will update the row's first name to say Lock but when you click on another row the previously Locked will revert to the first name. When I breakpoint regardless of a row displaying lock, the datatable always is the initial data (no "LOCK" data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line typically doesn't work for me

```
DataTable dt = DataGridUsers.DataSource as DataTable;
```

You might want to instead manage the DataSource in the session, by retrieving it out of session doing your modifications and then rebind it to the Grid.

You might also want to take a look at where the DataSource got bound to the grid the first time. Is is it running on the postback thus overwriting your changes.

Comment: AH.... I'm an ASP.Net noob and was getting the datatable on PageLoad from a webservice call. Didn't realize when I updated the table it reloads the page, added and If (IsPostBack) load from session type deal and works great. Thanks.